# How could we bring korban pesach in egypt if it was served as a deity?

Tags: passover, avodah-zarah, va-eira, parashat-vayikra, korban-pesach

It says [Shemos 8,22](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0208.htm#22):

> הֵ֣ן נִזְבַּ֞ח אֶת־תּֽוֹעֲבַ֥ת מִצְרַ֛יִם לְעֵֽינֵיהֶ֖ם וְלֹ֥א יִסְקְלֻֽנוּ׃ (...)
>
> "(...) If we sacrifice the god of the the Egyptians won't they stone us?" (Translation based on Rashi and Onklus)

[Rashi](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9902#showrashi=true) on Vayikra 1,2 - with regards to what qualifies as a *korban* that one can bring - quoting Sifri says:

> מן הבקר" - להוציא את הנעבד" -"from the cattle" to exclude a worshipped animal.

How could they sacrifice *korban pesach* in Egypt if it was served as a deity? Was there an exemption here to bring a worshipped animal or am I misunderstanding the Parsha? please answer with sources.

Comment: Use the analogy of the*sacred cows* of India. Any particular cow was not worshipped but all cows are treated as a a *sacred* object

Comment: A possible nuance, here ... Isn't it considered an official *karban* only when offered on a *mizbe'ach*? If so, did the Jews use a *mizbe'ach* for *Pesach Mitzrayim*?

Comment: Curious - Who translates תועבת as "gods"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses You are right, of course. Consider using Zevachim 8:1 as a source: if Neevad referred to a whole species, it could never get indistinguishably mixed up among other animals that we'd need to learn it isn't nullified.

Comment: They owned their own animals,like is brought by commentaries on makka of dever,that only the Egyptian animals died

Comment: @DanF artscroll translation see amend.The laws of all pesach offering are learnt from what Hashem commanded them in egypt in Shemos chapter 12 so even  if there wasn't blood applied on the mizbeach it still considerred a korban. in fact i seem to recall  (i wish i could provide a source) that Rav Tzvi Hirsch Kalisher (Talmid of the Chassam sofer) who lived in Israel said that one doesn't need a mizbeach rather just to place the blood in the place of the mizbeach for the korban Pesach to be eaten. Here Hashem commanded to put the blood on the doorposts & Lintel so i guess that made it a korban

Comment: @sam Read this from Shemos 10, 25 written after Dever and Borod ויאמר משה גם אתה תתן בידנו זבחים ועלות ועשינו you see the egyptians gave clal Yisroel their animals

Comment: @user15464 See Avodah Zarah 22b, top: לוקחין מהן בהמה לקרבן ואין חוששין... ולא משום נעבד... ואם איתא דפלחיה לא הוה מזבין ליה. So any animals that the Egyptians gave or sold to the Jews would have been ones they hadn't worshipped.

Comment: Didn't  they take sheep (rather than cattle)  for _Qorban Pesach_ in Egypt ([Shemot 12:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm#3))?

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, I expect that your first source is referring to a class of animals that's generally worshipped by a society, while your second source is referring to a particular animal that's been worshipped by individual worshippers.